# Error message when trying to set a DataGrid VeiwSource.View to null

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to set a bound datagrid so that nothing is selected.

When the page is loaded and `contactsListBySchoolIDViewSource` is created I can set it's `View` to null.
After the page is loaded and nothing is selected in the datagrid if I click the button the application runs fine.
If I click the button after a cell in the datagrid has been selected the `try..catch` does not catch an error but I get a messagebox that states:
  "Index is outside the bounds of the array."
If I click 'OK' on the messagebox nothing is selected in the datagrid as I would like.

The 'contactsViewSource' doesn't give me any problems.

I am using VS 2012, WPF, C# and .nrt 4.5.

My question is how do I stop the messagebox from displaying

```
<Page.Resources >
    <!-- Bound to a "details view" -->
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="contactsViewSource" Source="{Binding Contacts, Source={StaticResource mTAdminDataSet}}"/>

<!-- Bound to a datagrid -->
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="contactsListBySchoolIDViewSource" Source="{Binding ContactsListBySchoolID, Source={StaticResource mTAdminDataSet}}"/>

</Page.Resources>


    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

    MTAdmin.MTAdminDataSetTableAdapters.ContactsListBySchoolIDTableAdapter mTAdminDataSetContactsListBySchoolIDTableAdapter = new MTAdmin.MTAdminDataSetTableAdapters.ContactsListBySchoolIDTableAdapter();

    mTAdminDataSetContactsListBySchoolIDTableAdapter.Fill(mTAdminDataSet.ContactsListBySchoolID, schoolId);
    contactsListBySchoolIDViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("contactsListBySchoolIDViewSource")));
    contactsListBySchoolIDViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo(null);


    MTAdmin.MTAdminDataSetTableAdapters.ContactsListBySchoolIDTableAdapter mTAdminDataSetContactsListBySchoolIDTableAdapter = new MTAdmin.MTAdminDataSetTableAdapters.ContactsListBySchoolIDTableAdapter();
    mTAdminDataSetContactsListBySchoolIDTableAdapter.Fill(mTAdminDataSet.ContactsListBySchoolID, schoolId);
    contactsListBySchoolIDViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("contactsListBySchoolIDViewSource")));
    contactsListBySchoolIDViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo(null);

    //other code.....

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

}

    private void contactsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
    //bound to grid with details(textboxes)
            contactsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo(null);

    //bound to the datagrid

 // THIS IS THE LINE OF CODE THROWING THE ERROR 
            contactsListBySchoolIDViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo(null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Thanks!!

Comment: OMG What in the world is this? `MTAdmin.MTAdminDataSetTableAdapters.ContactsListBySchoolIDTableAdapter mTAdminDataSetContactsListBySchoolIDTableAdapter = new MTAdmin.MTAdminDataSetTableAdapters.ContactsListBySchoolIDTableAdapter();` - Dude, use `var` please. This is not java.

Comment: Also, `CollectionViewSource` is intended to be used in XAML, not in procedural code.

Comment: If you are getting: "Index is outside the bounds of the array." then you are likely trying to look into the Rows collection of the GRID.  Please show us the exact line that is throwing the error.

Comment: the line of code that is throwing the error is: `contactsListBySchoolIDViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo(null);` In the button click event.

Comment: `MTAdmin.MTAdminDataSetTableAdapters.ContactsListBySchoolIDTableAdapter mTAdminDataSetContactsListBySchoolIDTableAdapter` was use because `var` cannot be used outside a Method. The code may not be the best but I'm learning.

Comment: I don't see anything that should give Index is outside the bounds of the array.  You could try MoveCurrentToPosition(-1) though.

Comment: I tried using the `MoveCurrentToPosition(-1)` and received the same error message.